# How to select the first div among other div siblings with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, css-selectors

How do I select the div that contains "bar"?

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="foo">
    <div>bar</div> <!--this one-->
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>123</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for the editing Dan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fastest as it does not use pseudo-selectors

```
$('#foo > div').first()

// same as
$('#foo > div').eq(0)

// same as
$('#foo > div').slice(0,1)
```

Comment: also, you can get in the habbit of just using .eq() - e.g. `$( '#foo > div' ).eq(0)` to get the first element or `eq(-1)` to get the last. Also, .slice() for ranges, like `$( '#foo > div' ).slice(2,4) to get the 3rd, 4th and 5th elements

Comment: @DanHeberden, I included these additional examples for you

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
$("#foo :first-child");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want based on contents rather than position, you could use this:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

`$("div:contains('bar')")`